# How can I get the global position of a Node3D in Godot 4?

Tags: godot, godot4

I want to position one node to another, but they are under different parent nodes. How can I set one of the node's position to the other's, without interfering with the parent nodes' positions? Btw, the node3d with the position i'm trying to find has a random position

i've tried Node3D.global_position() and Node3D.global_translate (AI told me to try it). I know how to set global position, just not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Godot 3 for `Spatial` you would do `node.global_transform.origin`, and this continues to work in Godot 4 for `Node3D`.

However, in Godot 4 you can now use `node.global_position` for `Node3D` which brings it in line with `Node2D`.

The official documentation for [`global_position`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node3d.html#class-node3d-property-global-position) says

> Global position of this node. This is equivalent to global_transform.origin

Both `global_transform.origin` and `global_position` are properties, that you can get:

```
prints(node.global_transform.origin, node.global_position)
```

Or set:

```
node.global_transform.origin = Vector3.ZERO
node.global_position = Vector3.ZERO
```

---

Apparently you were trying to use it as a method `Node3D.global_position()` (since you added parenthesis, it would be trying to call it, which it can't since it is a `Vector3` not a `Callable`).

And also `Node3D.global_translate` which apparently you tried to use as a property... Well, it is a method which you can use to move the `Node3D`.

The documentation on [`global_translate`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node3d.html#class-node3d-method-global-translate) says:

> Moves the global (world) transformation by Vector3 offset. The offset is in global coordinate system.

You would use it like this:

```
node.global_translate(some_offset)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
node.global_position += some_offset
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
node.global_transform.origin += some_offset
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
node.global_transform.origin = node.global_transform.origin + some_offset
```